# executing stored procedure via odbc from axapta

Tags: sql, odbc, axapta, procedure

we're currently executing a stored procedure ( ms sql 2008 ) from axapta ( ax 2009 ).
the sp is indeed quite large and the obfuscating effect is, that the sp doesn't work, if triggered via odbc.
a simple "exec sp ..." executed via ssms works fine.
if we remove some of the last queries executed in the sp, the sp also works fired from ax.
nevertheless, the queries which are removed are working fine in "single mode".

are there ANY limitations for executing stored procedures via odbc? i even don't think that it has anything to do with axapta....

thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed.
adding "set nocount on" at the very start of the stored procedure, behaviour is as intended.
seems, that there IS a limit for returning affected line results.